# Google Chrome in Kubuntu does not use file manager to show files?

Tags: kubuntu, google-chrome, dolphin

Every time I try to show a file I have downloaded file with Google Chrome in Dolphin, it's opened in a webpage like this:

[image]

Any idea on how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Downloads. At there, right-click the downloaded file. Choose 'Open with...' and select the File Manager.

Hope this helps!